# I can't assign a value to a 2d array

Tags: c++, c++11

So this is my first attempt to write a program using classes in c++. As an exercise, I'm trying to create a 2d-array class that can do certain things. This is a part of the code in the main.cpp that my class has to be able to run.

```
int main()
{
    array2d<double> ar(2,2);

    ar(1,1) = 1; 
    ar(0,0) = 2;
    ar(0,1) = 3;
    ar(1,0) = 4;

    auto X{ar};

    array2d<double> c(2,2);
    c = ar;
    c.diagonal(1) = 5; //c(1,1) = 5 
}
```

And this is my code. I'm getting an error in the diagonal function "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment". I can't figure out what I should do. The purpose of this function is to assign values in the diagonal elements of the array.

```
template<typename T>
class array2d
{
private:
    int n,m;
    vector<T> vec;

public:
    array2d(int M, int N)
    : n{N}, m{M}
    {
        vector<T> vec1(n*m);
        vec = vec1;
    }

    array2d(array2d<T> &arr)
    : n{arr.N()} , m{arr.M()}
    {
        vec = arr.V();
    }

    array2d &operator=(array2d<T>  & arr){
        vec = arr.V();
        return *this;
    }

    T &operator()(int i,int j)
    {
        auto it = vec.begin();
        it += i*n+j;
        return *it;
    }  

    T diagonal(int a)
    {
        auto x= *this;
        return x(a,a);
    }

    int M (){return m;}
    int N (){return n;}
    vector<T> V(){return vec;}
};
```

Edit: I have another problem. Next thing my class should be able to run is this 
`ar = X.transpose();`
But I'm getting 2 errors:

*error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'array2d&' from an rvalue of type 'array2d'*
**AND**

*note:   initializing argument 1 of 'array2d array2d::operator=(array2d&) [with T = double]'|*

My function is this.

```
array2d<T> transpose  ()
    {
        auto &y = *this ;

        array2d<T> x(y.N(),y.M()) ;

        for (int i{0};i<x.d1();i++){
            for (int j{0}; j<x.d2();j++){
                x(i,j) = y(j,i);
            }
        };

        return x;
    }
```

Comment: `diagonal` should return a reference.

Comment: @ΆλκηςΧαλκιαδακης Regarding "_that worked_": Did you make it `auto& x= *this;` too? Otherwise you'll be returning a `T&` into a temporary `vector<T>`.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo No, I didn't. It doesn't seem to make any difference though.

Comment: You don't need to write a copy constructor and assignment operator in this case. The compiler will generate them for you. (Not to mention that there are a few problems with your custom copy ctor & assignment, such as parameters being non-const references.)

Comment: @ΆλκηςΧαλκιαδακης So, the function now looks like this? `T& diagonal(int a)
    {
        auto x= *this;
        return x(a,a);
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made miscellaneous changes and have commented in the code:

```
// bad practice:
// using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class array2d {
private:
    // use an unsigned int for dimensions
    unsigned m, n;
    std::vector<T> vec;

public:
    // initialize the vector in the member initializer list too:
    array2d(unsigned M, unsigned N) : m{M}, n{N}, vec(m * n)
    {}

    // arr should be a const&:
    array2d(const array2d<T>& arr) : m{arr.m}, n{arr.n}, vec(arr.vec)
    {}

    // arr should be a const&:
    array2d& operator=(const array2d<T>& arr) {
        vec = arr.vec;
        // n and m should also be copied:
        m = arr.m;
        n = arr.n;
        return *this;
    }

    T& operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j) {
        // unnecessary iterator arithmetic replaced
        return vec[i * n + j];
    }

    // a const version to be used in const contexts:
    const T& operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j) const {
        return vec[i * n + j];
    }

    // You should return a T& and it should be a reference to
    // a T inside vec, not to a copy that will become invalid as soon as the function
    // returns.
    T& diagonal(unsigned a) {
        return (*this)(a, a);
    }

    // this function should be const since you are not supposed to change "this"
    array2d<T> transpose() const {
        // y is just confusing
        // auto& y = *this;

        // Use your member variables (or call the functions M() and N()) directly.
        array2d<T> x(n, m);

        // d1() and d2() doesn't exist in the code you've shown, but they are not
        // needed:
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < x.m; i++) {
            for(unsigned j = 0; j < x.n; j++) {
                x(i, j) = (*this)(j, i);
            }
        }

        return x;
    }

    unsigned M() { return m; }
    unsigned N() { return n; }
    std::vector<T> V() { return vec; }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot.  But I have a couple of questions. I can't quite understand what changes if I don't put those "const" that you added? And what is the difference between initiating the values inside the body of the function and the way you did it?

Comment: @ΆλκηςΧαλκιαδακης Glad to hear it!

The `const`s serves the purpose of making the member functions available when an object is in a `const` context. Without them, your objects can only be used by standard library functions practically promising to change your object in one way or another. It also allows the compiler to make optimizations based on the fact that it knows that the object (this) won't be changed.

The difference between initializing members in the member initializer list and to copy assign values to them in the constructor body:

Comment: `1)` Some types can not be default constructed. `2)` It's costly (in terms of performance) to first default construct an object and then copy assign a new value to it.

Comment: Regarding `const` again: Look at the `transpose()` function. I added `const` because it's not supposed to change the object - but then compilation failed because it was trying to call another member function (`T& operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j)`) that is **not**  `const` so compilation fails. That's why the `const T& operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j) const` function is needed.

Comment: Ok got it I think. Again thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @AlkisChalkiadakis Great! You're welcome! Happy New Year!